# How to check if the cell is not blanked, then trigger the event?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I have now is to do simple condition checking and trigger event, if CEO Approval box and Account Approval box are both checked, trigger send email event and set value of inform column as informed. It works fine.

[image]

```
function sendEmailver4() {
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1")
const CEO_col = sheet.getRange(2, 26, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
const Acc_col = sheet.getRange(2, 27, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
const receiverCol = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
//msg body sheet
const templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("template").getRange(1,1).getValue();

for(var i=2; i <= receiverCol.length; i++) {
var CEO_box = sheet.getRange(i, 26);
var Acc_box = sheet.getRange(i, 27);
var couse_col = sheet.getRange(i, 8).getValues();
var receiverName = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValues();
var receiverEmail = sheet.getRange(i, 19).getValue();
var inform_cell = sheet.getRange(i, 28);
if (receiverEmail === "") {
break;
}

if(Acc_box.isChecked() && CEO_box.isChecked() && inform_cell.getValue() =="uninformed") {
var subject = "Hi" + couse_col
var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}",receiverName).replace("{courseName}", couse_col)
console.log("send Email to:"+ receiverEmail)
MailApp.sendEmail(receiverEmail, subject, messageBody);
inform_cell.setValue("informed");

}
}
}
```

I would like to add one more checking besides the above condition: if the Receiver Name column is blanked, don't send email and pop up error message in spreadsheet. I try something like below to catch error if name is blanked, but doesn't work. email just still sending despite the name is blanked.

```
if(Acc_box.isChecked() && CEO_box.isChecked() && inform_cell.getValue() =="uninformed") {
var subject = "Hi" + couse_col
var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}",receiverName).replace("{courseName}", couse_col)
console.log("send Email to:"+ receiverEmail)
try{
if (receiverName !== "") {
MailApp.sendEmail(receiverEmail, subject, messageBody);
inform_cell.setValue("informed");
}
} catch(error) {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(error)
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google script - Not equal to not working correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805699/google-script-not-equal-to-not-working-correctly)

Comment: "Not equal to" is NOT the opposite of "equal to".  [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#comparison_operators)

Answer (score 0):

**If both columns 23 and  24 are checked**

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart > 22 && e.range.columnStart < 25 && e.range.rowStart > 1 ) {
    if(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,23,1,2).getValues().flat().every(e => e == "TRUE")) {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,25).setValue("informed");
      //send email
    }
  }
}
```

> You cannot run these functions without supplying the event object. If you attempt to run from the script editor without supplying the event object you will get an error.  The onEdit trigger is a simple trigger meaning that it cannot perform functions that require permission.  If you need tp perform commands that require permission you must create an installable trigger either programmatically or through the editors trigger panel.

There are several limitations running scripts this way.  You will have difficulty using alert and prompt boxes.  They are fairly difficult to debug because the onEdit is not easily run in debug mode so you are left having to edit the appropriate elements on the desired sheet."

Learn more from onEdit event object:

```
"function onMyEdit(e){Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))};
//{""authMode"":""FULL"",""oldValue"":""10.0"",""range"":{""columnEnd"":6,""columnStart"":6,""rowEnd"":6,""rowStart"":6},""source"":{},""triggerUid"":"""",""user"":{""email"":"""",""nickname"":""""},""value"":""pp""}
```